# Hiding embedded.mobileprovision from IOS app

Tags: jailbreak, ad-hoc-distribution, sideloading, mobileprovision, ios-app-signing

I'm trying to resign ios app using my own certificate and after resign it it produce a file "embedded.mobileprovision". is there a way to delete this file or hide it?

I need the app to work after resigning it and hide/delete the "embedded.mobileprovision" file.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete that file for two reasons:

1. It is owned by `installd` and not `mobile`, which you're running as.
2. Your app would no longer launch without it.

In order to "hide" it, the most reasonable approach would be to take a look at what syscalls the app uses to look for that file, and then inject a custom dylib to hook those syscall invocations and patch the returned data.

Comment: If i want to use zsign to sign the app, is there a script or a way to hide it? What I know for instance Snapchat is blocking based on this file.